# Retrieve theme colours progammatically

Tags: python, themes, wxpython

I am writing a Python application and I want to get the colour of the panel (window) that contains the gui. This is theme dependent. Is it possible to retrieve theme colours programmatically? I've tried:

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Panel colour')
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add(panel)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(main_sizer)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()
        print(self.GetBackgroundColour())
        print(panel.GetBackgroundColour())

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, frame):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, frame)
        lbl_description = wx.StaticText(self, label='Hello world')
        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add(lbl_description, flag=wx.ALL, border=10)
        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    screen_app = wx.App()
    main_frame = MainFrame()
    screen_app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Just a hint, You need check GUI toolkit documentation. Default Ubuntu/Unity is based on GTK.

Comment: Tried that. Using wxPython I tried print(self.GetBackgroundColour()) to get the colour of a panel, but it always returns (255, 255, 255, 255)

Comment: Could you edit the question and add a complete test code.

Comment: @user.dz I've added my code to the question